Virtual CRAN repo does not include local packages
We are using an company specific instance of Artifactory hosted at https://company.jfrog.io/ and we use it to host packages for R.
We've configured a remote repository cran-remote to mirror the official CRAN repository (https://cran.r-project.org/). We've also configured cran-local to host private, company-specific packages. And finally we created a cran virtual repository which is a combination of cran-remote and cran-local. Normally we are able to just have users set up the virtual repo in R and they can install both local and remote packages, but as of about a week ago, only remote packages are available from the virtual repo. For example, we set the users up in R with
options("repos")
$repos
$repos$cran
[1] "https://user:pass@company.jfrog.io/artifactory/cran/"

But running available.packages() inside of R doesn't show any packages in cran-local, just those in cran-remote. I can check each of the sub repos as well
# Virtual
nrow(available.packages("https://user:pass@company.jfrog.io/artifactory/cran/src/contrib"))
# [1] 21096

# Remote
nrow(available.packages("https://user:pass@company.jfrog.io/artifactory/cran-remote/src/contrib"))
# [1] 21096

# Local
nrow(available.packages("https://user:pass@company.jfrog.io/artifactory/cran-local/src/contrib"))
# [1] 11

# compare names
length(setdiff( 
 rownames(available.packages("https://user:pass@company.jfrog.io/artifactory/cran-local/src/contrib")),  
 rownames(available.packages("https://user:pass@company.jfrog.io/artifactory/cran-remote/src/contrib"))
))
# [1] 11 #(no overlapping names)

There are no duplicated names or anything like that. The values from local are just not in the virtual repo. This used to work just fine but stopped working ~Jul 19.
Why are the packages from cran-local not appearing in the virtual cran repo? This does not appear to be a problem with other repo types such as npm or pypi.
You can see the configuration in this screen shot


Same issue with me, I managed to install local packages through renv::install. I also have to spell out the package version like my_package@1.0.1. Could you try this let me know? This also has been happening to me around the same date.

We don't use renv for most projects. I did just try to install it. And while renv itself installs just fine, it still cannot find local packages. Maybe you already had packages cached in your renv project files.

@MrFlick, so I tried that on bare machines too and the renv worked. yeah sorry not sure why it didn't work for you.
